# What's the most efficient way to get a variable length of rows w.r.t each group of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

To illustrate my question clearly, for a dummy dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 'Y' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
```

How can I get top 1 row of group A and top 2 rows of group B, and get rid of the rest rows of each group? By the way, the real dataset is big with hundreds of thousands of rows and thousands of groups.

And the output looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['B', 'B', 'A'], 'Y' : [1, 2, 3]})
```

My main gripe is `.groupby().head()` only gives me a fixed length of rows within each group, and I want have a different number of rows of different groups.

Comment: Maybe provide an example output?

Comment: When you say get - if you want them independently then: `df[df['X'] == 'A'][0:1]` and `df[df['X]' == 'B'][0:2]`

Comment: That's a way of doing it, but concatenating thousands of them would not be much efficient, and take a long time.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is create a dictionary contains the number of rows each group should keep, and in the `groupby.apply`, use the `g.name` as the key to look up the value in the dictionary, with the `head` method you can keep different rows for each group:

```
rows_per_group = {"A": 1, "B": 2}    
df.groupby("X", group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.head(rows_per_group[g.name]))

#   X   Y
#2  A   3
#0  B   1
#1  B   2
```

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks for the comment!